# Behave - format=plainb error when running scripts

Tags: python-3.x, python-behave

I am new to behave. I am trying to execute script using " behave --no-capture -f plainb " and I am getting below error.

```
usage: behave [options] [ [DIR|FILE|FILE:LINE] ]+
behave: error: format=plainb is unknown
```

However if I run script using behave, script gets executed. I want to run script using above code as I want to see output in the terminal to verify few things are working as expected.

Can anyone please shed some light on why I am getting this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct command is:

```
behave --no-capture -f plain
```

Some useful details with:

```
behave --format help
```